# Best solution for a multi-token chain and a custom transaction payment pallet

Tags: transaction-fees, pallet-asset

1. What is the best solution for implementing a chain without a native token, but perhaps multiple assets, some of which can be used for transaction fees ?
   Is it practical to replace the pallet Balances and provide a multi-token based pallet (e.g. pallet assets) ?
2. What is the best way to allow the execution of some transactions without taking additional fees for one specific pallet ? Is it a good solution to implement a custom fee system for that pallet that basically takes a fee only if the transaction fails, and returns it if succeeds. This is to avoid network spamming based on invalid extrinsics. Based on this design, is there any security implication I am missing ?